OnPreDraw return false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@b5f1a7c
Suddenly I keep getting this message in the console
402 W/ViewTreeObserver(19536): onPreDraw return false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@e448b5a and it repeats many times
I've recently updated Flutter to the latest version maybe that is the problem?
and this affects colors, width, heights, and scrolling features in the app
Widgets Should look like this
But now it looks like this
Before I upgraded to the Flutter version it was working just fine I don't know why this happens
